# An early Father, Who am I

Tags: riddle

Hints;

> I cross the lines: madness and genius
>
> A early father I was born
>
> Citadels I enjoy a plotting
>
> An enigma I remain to those who know me

Who am I?

Answer (score 4):

I cross the lines: madness and genius

> Nimrod was both a genius for leading his people and also mean and strange

A early father I was born

> Nimrod is an early character from the Bible

Citadels I enjoy a plotting

> Nimrod built the famous tower of Babel

An enigma I remain to those who know me

> Nimrod was an enigma, because he was actually correct in hoping for mankind to have a common language, but woefully punished by God who wanted differently.  It's the paradox of universal difference and sameness.

Comment: If this is the answer then there's [another reason](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Enigma_Variations#Variation_IX_.28Adagio.29_.27Nimrod.27) for "An enigma I remain ...".

Answer (score 0):

> Charles Babbage

He cross the lines: madness and genius

> Charles Babbage is the father of the computer.

Citadels I enjoy a plotting

> I am not sure about this.

An enigma I remain to those who know me

> Computer use 0 and 1 so it's kind of encryption for some of us.